Como Organizar os arquivos pyd no pyinstaller
desde que comecei a estudar programação eu me deparei com a necessidade de criar executáveis dos pequenos programas que criei. Porém tentei pesquisar sobre e o que eu encontrava não conseguia chegar ao resultado esperado.
A o executar:

pyinstaller main.py --onedir --console --clean --add-data="icon.png:." --contents-directory='Config' -i="icon.png"

cria o diretório dist/main/ contendo a pasta Config e o Executável, que funciona perfeitamente. Porém eu gostaria de colocar todos arquivos Python Extension Module (pyd) dentro de um diretório como exemplo pythondll e colocar tudo dentro da distpath sem a necessidade de usar o contents-directory.
Resultado Esperado
dist/main/contents
Aonde o 'contents' seria:

pythondll
pasta extra
.dlls
.exe


Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Evite a utilização de imagens na formulação da sua pergunta. Você pode utilizar dir > arquivos.txt para facilitar a cópia dos nomes. Deixe apenas o básico evitando excesso de informação.

@DanielIkenaga obrigado pela dica, eu editei a postagem.
